# User activity feed (ala facebook). How to group similar activities?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

In a movies DB project I'm working on, each user have an activity feed. I want to group similar activities, like how Facebook does it but little different.

For example if an user writes a review for a movie, and one minute later he also votes for that movie and 5 minutes later he upload a trailer for that movie, I want to show it together (grouped) in the activity feed.

I think the best is to group it when querying the database but I don't think its possible in this case because I use a really big JOIN to get all the data:

```
SELECT ua.datetime, ua.imdbID, ua.personID, sa.activityID, sa.activity, m.title, m.year, p.name, umv.vote, upv.vote, r.review, t.youTubeID, ps.filename, ph.filename
FROM user_activity ua
JOIN sys_activities sa ON ua.activityID = sa.activityID
LEFT OUTER JOIN movies m ON ua.imdbID = m.imdbID
LEFT OUTER JOIN persons p ON ua.personID = p.personID
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_movies_vote umv ON umv.userID = ua.userID AND umv.imdbID = ua.imdbID
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_persons_vote upv ON upv.userID = ua.userID AND upv.personID = ua.personID
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews r ON r.userID = ua.userID AND r.imdbID = ua.imdbID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        select imdbID, userID, youTubeID, max(hd) as MaxTrailerStatus
        from trailers
        group by imdbID
        ) t ON ua.imdbID = t.imdbID AND ua.userID = t.userID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        select imdbID, filename, max(main) as MaxPosterStatus
        from posters
        group by imdbID
        ) ps ON ua.imdbID = ps.imdbID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        select personID, filename, max(main) as MaxPhotosStatus
        from photos
        group by personID
        ) ph ON ua.personID = ph.personID
WHERE ua.userID = ?
ORDER BY ua.datetime DESC
```

I want to know how to do it either by modifying the query or using PHP.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd likely group on the item id of the item being modified - which in this case looks like: ua.imdbID.

Once you do that, you'll lose out on the other rows of data, so you'd use GROUP_CONCAT to get all related IDs.

GROUP_CONCAT(sa.activityID);

So your end result would be:

```
SELECT ua.datetime, ua.imdbID, ua.personID, GROUP_CONCAT(sa.activityID), sa.activity, m.title, m.year, p.name, umv.vote, upv.vote, r.review, t.youTubeID, ps.filename, ph.filename
FROM user_activity ua
JOIN sys_activities sa ON ua.activityID = sa.activityID
LEFT OUTER JOIN movies m ON ua.imdbID = m.imdbID
LEFT OUTER JOIN persons p ON ua.personID = p.personID
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_movies_vote umv ON umv.userID = ua.userID AND umv.imdbID = ua.imdbID
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_persons_vote upv ON upv.userID = ua.userID AND upv.personID = ua.personID
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews r ON r.userID = ua.userID AND r.imdbID = ua.imdbID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        select imdbID, userID, youTubeID, max(hd) as MaxTrailerStatus
        from trailers
        group by imdbID
        ) t ON ua.imdbID = t.imdbID AND ua.userID = t.userID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        select imdbID, filename, max(main) as MaxPosterStatus
        from posters
        group by imdbID
        ) ps ON ua.imdbID = ps.imdbID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        select personID, filename, max(main) as MaxPhotosStatus
        from photos
        group by personID
        ) ph ON ua.personID = ph.personID
WHERE ua.userID = ?  GROUP BY ua.imdbID


ORDER BY ua.datetime DESC
```

Comment: It's working, but not the way I'm looking for. The method you proposed erases all the data when grouping it. So I get only one result per activity because its merging everything.

Comment: The data from the fields you need to get can be gotten by using GROUP_CONCAT() function.

Comment: "The data from the fields you need to get can be gotten by using GROUP_CONCAT() function", @ajacian81, can you explain this, how can one grab the rest of the data from the GROUP_CONCAT() also when GROUP BY is present?